# Partitions of numbers - Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I am having some trouble with the following question.

Prove that for $n \ge 2$, $p(n) -p(n-2)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with at most one part of size 1.

I can see that by differencing them, the two partitions is going to only produce partitions of size 1 and 2. What is the next step to prove that these partitions only contain at most one part of size 1?

Comment: "..to prove that these partitions only contain at most one part of size 1" Which partitions do you mean here?

Comment: The number of partitions equal to the difference between p(n) and p(n-2)

Comment: My question was: "**which** partitions?" So a correct answer on that cannot be a **number** of partitions.

Answer (score 3):

For $n$ large enough there are $p(n-2)$ ways to partition integer $n$ is such a way that $1$ appears at least twice in it.

This because such a partition is exactly a partition of integer $n-2$ supplemented with two "ones".

There are $p(n)$ partitions of $n$ in total so $p(n)-p(n-2)$ of them do *not* have $1$ at least twice in it.